# EXTJS 4.2 - ComboBox - How to Encode input text

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4, sencha-architect

My memory store  proxy has encoded data.

Does anymore know how user input typed into a combobox can be encoded to search against the memory proxy store.

The combobox uses typeahead and is editable.

My understanding is that typed user input into a combobox is handled as a string.

Fiddle example here

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/m31

In my example,  enter & to see the issue.

Comment: How is the value displayed in the ui? encoded?

Comment: The value is displayed decoded, it seems that the combobox decodes the encoded data.

Comment: Can you share some of the code to see?

Comment: Hi there Seram,  I added a fiddle link to my post.

Comment: I got around this by overriding the localQuery and encoding the queryParm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by creating an override for localQuery and encoding queryParam.